# How to create a sliding side border WPF?

Tags: wpf

So, if you have seen the Windows 11 Store UI. I want to replicate the border or the sliding bar on the side where every time you click a button the border or sliding bar would go to that button and center it self in the middle.

[image: Windows 11 Sliding Side Bar]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom template for the button that has an ItemControl of a single border on the left along with the button content, and when it is selected and animate it.